# User Control location and update during development

Tags: user-controls, genexus

I have an user control, with name Test1 for example, in the directory:

C:\Models...\CSharpModel\web\Test1

Even when I delete it in that directory, the user control still works in the webpanel on the browser. Why this happens? How can I make sure the user control is deleted?

And how can I make sure the user control is updated? Because even when I change the version, do the install command, restart the browser and make sure the browser is refreshed properly (or test it in another browser), sometimes I don't get the lasted changes that I have made in the javascript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Must increase the version number `<Version>X.X</Version>` located in YourUserControl.control. This is how GeneXus knows if the UC was updated.
2. Close GeneXus.
3. After updating any file within a usercontrol, you have to copy those files to your GeneXus Installation Folder/UserControls.
4. Run Genexus.exe /install
5. Run GeneXus
6. Build All (GeneXus will detect version change in your UC and automatically copy UC files)